# How to get List<String> from JSON list using Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am new to Android. I need to get a list of strings from a JSON list. It will be added to a `Spinner` list. I have the list on server like

```
[{"bgroup":"A+"},{"bgroup":"A1+"},{"bgroup":"A1-"}].
```

tried with Retrofit Scalars.
Response  as

```
[{"bgroup":"A+"},{"bgroup":"A1+"},{"bgroup":"A1-"}]
```

but error detecting as:

> Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3 path $[0]*

Any better way to retrieve the list of strings from the JSON?

Comment: It clearly tells you that it cannot read a string from where an object comes from. Why not just create a mapping to have `List<Mapping>` and extract a string directly from `Mapping.bgroup` later?

Comment: If you used same string for custom data object then retrofit automatically give you formatted data object with values.  So use same key. and use dependency  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Thanks for answer. Can you give simple List<mapping> example for this scenario ?

Comment: @MdSal It's very easy: just create your own something like `class Mapping { String bgroup; }` and declare your Retrofit interface to return `List<Mapping>` -- then you can easily extract the `bgroup` property.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Yes. I don't want to create Model class for field. bcz having more then one field like "bgroup". As of now i have created model and its working. Thanks all

Comment: @MdSal Trust me, it's much easier to create a simple wrapper class rather than add custom serialization strategies.

Comment: @Lyubomyr Yaah.. Created simple class and using for retrieve values. Its simpe and easier too.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is sample code :

```
 GroupService groupService = createService(GroupService.class);

 Call<List<Groups>> groupCall = groupService.getGroups();

    groupCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Groups>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<List<Groups>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();

            }
        });
```

Interfaces :

```
public interface GroupService {

@GET("<URL>")
Call<List<Groups>> getGroups();
}
```

Also create model name Groups.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following model class (parcelable)

```
package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Example implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("bgroup")
@Expose
private String bgroup;

public String getBgroup() {
return bgroup;
}

public void setBgroup(String bgroup) {
this.bgroup = bgroup;
}


    protected Example(Parcel in) {
        bgroup = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(bgroup);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Example> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Example>() {
        @Override
        public Example createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Example(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Example[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Example[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Than create interface class like this

```
public interface ApiService {

@GET("<URL>")
Call<List<Example>> getBloodGroups();
}
```

And finally call retrofit like following :

```
Call<List<Example>> call = new RestClient(this).getApiService()
                .getBloodGroups();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Example>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Example>> call, Response<List<Example>> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Example>> call, Throwable throwable) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes. your answer should work. But i would like to use without Model class. Any other simple way pls?

Comment: So you want to get response as JSON String only ??

Comment: I want to add response values to List<String>, then i can use to spinner dropdown.

Finally i have created simple model class. Its working now. Thanks @Krishna Meena